# How to make classes separately for each word in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

To begin with I would like to say that I write with the help of django.

The question itself. I have models in the folder models.py, there is specified in fact all that I output in the post, I also have a file views.py and in general everything works fine, the posts are displayed on the page that I need. But! I need to modify the posts, for example, change the color of the header, make that one was after the other, but I can not assign just a class or an idi to a certain header or a certain piece of text, because they are all united in one line, look at the code and understand.

```
<body>
    {% for post in post_list %}
        <h3>{{post.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ post.description}}</p>
        <p>{{ post.time_posts}}</p>
            {{ post.author }}

    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

If i put a class front example `<div class="prjtitle"><p>{{ post.time_posts}}</p></div>` 
Then I have that when working in css with this prjtitle class I move absolutely all headings and they just merge 1 in 1.

How can I make it so that I can edit almost every word with css classes or idi.